# Represent very large numbers with float/double precision

Tags: c#

I would like to show very large numbers in an application (incremental game). The exponent can be larger than 100,000 (one hundred thousand) so `double` or `float` will meet their limitations. I know about the `BigInteger` type but I read that it can be slow and I do not need more than 5 digts of precision on the significand, so it might not be a good option

An example of a number could be 1.2345*10^100000. In this case I do not care about any decimal after the 5th (anywhere between 5-15 digts of precision would be fine)

I need to do multiple operations (multiplication, addition, power, log) on the number in a 30ms loop so it should be fast. How can I do this in a good way? Are there any libraries or do I need to make my own?

It would also be great if I could represent the number with different notations like scientific, engineering, alphabetic, standard (million, billion, ..., septillion, octillion, nonillion), etc.

Comment: "he exponent can be larger than 100,000 (one hundred thousand) so double or float will meet their limitations." - because in your universe 100.000 is larger than 10 exp 308? You seem to never have read the limitations of the double data type, OR you really do NOT make your point here. From what you say, you already are done at double and there is zero need for anything else.

Comment: Out of curiosity: where do such big numbers occur? I kind of remember that the number of elementary particles in the universe is 10^80 or so.

Comment: @TomTom The *exponent* is larger than 100,000. Yes, in this universe 100,000 is much greater than 308 :)

Comment: @TomTom 10^100000 is MUCH bigger than 10^308, and clearly outside of the range of double.

Comment: And @KlausGütter it is for an incremental game. Its just fictional numbers that can keep growing exponentially for a very very long time.

Comment: "*(million, billion, ..., septillion, octillion, nonillion), etc.*" -- I don't think we have words that go up to `10^100,000`, or anywhere remotely close. I'm not sure you've grasped just how mind-bogglingly big `10^100000` is...

Comment: You could rolll your own floating-point type with 32-bit exponent. If you don't care about all the edge-cases (NaN, denormalized numbers, infinities) it's not rocket science.

Comment: ... especially if you only care about the 5 or so most significant digits: you bypass a lot of complexity by doing that

Comment: Have a look here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114911/how-do-idle-games-handle-such-large-numbers

Comment: The 'slowness' you can experience from using BigInteger is related to how large the numbers get so your best bet may be to try it first.

Comment: Or - calculate with the logarithm of the number, then you only have to write one new method for formatting th exponential for display.

Comment: Thereis no way to do that efficiently. THe "standard" approach is do use multiple double to define first alarger more coarse coordinate, then the next one works within that. No standard CPU wil be able to handle that - and there is no way to represent that in any sensible way outside of scientific notation.

Comment: @KlausGütter About first comment: 10^80 may be an order of magnitude ot the particles in the universe, Though it doesn't mean that nothing can have a bigger representation. For instance, if you consider merely the _pairs_ of particle in the universe, then you can approximately square that number. When you start do combinatorics, things get pretty larger than any number of "things" we can set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about if there's already a library for this, but you can try to write your own class for LargeNumbers:

```
class LargeNumber
{
    double Value;
    int Mantissa;
}
```

Then you can override the addition, multiplication operators etc. 
Sure you have to do some math there

**Edit:**
Yes, you have to know about how the exponentials work and it is not trivial, but not too difficult.

Example of some math for addition operation, in the case where: 
 firstNumber.Mantissa> secondNumber.Mantissa> 0:

```
...
var expDifference = firstNumber.Mantissa - secondNumber.Mantissa;
if(expDifference > 5)
{
   return firstNumber;
}
if(expDifference < 5)
{
   return new LargeNumber
   {
       Value = firstNumber.Value*(10^expDifference) + secondNumber.Value,
       Mantissa= firstNumber.Mantissa
   }
}
...
```

Comment: Hmm, yes. This would be a good answer if you eleborate a bit on "some math".

Comment: This was also my thought. I just hoped that this library already existed :)

Comment: What you call `Mantissa` would usually be named `Exponent`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to approximately represent huge numbers is to work only with the logarithm of the number.
The usual arithmetic operations transfer quite simple to the logarithm. We exploit the following formulae:

- log(*a* * *b*) = log(*a*) + log(*b*)
- log(*a* / *b*) = log(*a*) - log(*b*)
- log(*a* ^ *b*) = *b* * log(*a*)

The most complex being the addition/subtraction (it is numerically advantagous to choose the bigger number as *a*):

- log(*a* + *b*) = log(*a* *(1 + *b*/*a*)) = log(*a*) + log(1 + *b*/*a*))

As the logarithm is defined ony for strictly positive numbers, in order to represent negative numbers and zero, we have to add the sign as extra bookkeeping variable.

All together, I came up with the following class, implementing addition, subtraction, unary plus and minus, multiplication, division, logarithm, exponentiation and a full set of comparison operators:

```
struct HugeNumber : IEquatable<HugeNumber>, IComparable<HugeNumber>
{
    private int _sign; // -1, 0 or +1
    private double _log;
    
    private HugeNumber(int sign, double log)
    {
        _sign = sign;
        _log = log;
    }
    
    public static implicit operator HugeNumber(double number)
    {
        if (number > 0.0)
            return new HugeNumber(1, Math.Log10(number));
        else if (number < 0.0)
            return new HugeNumber(-1, Math.Log10(-number));
        else
            return new HugeNumber(0, 0.0);
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator*(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2)
    {
        return new HugeNumber(n1._sign * n2._sign, n1._log + n2._log);
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator/(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2)
    {
        return new HugeNumber(n1._sign * n2._sign, n1._log - n2._log);
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator+(HugeNumber n)
    {
        return n;
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator-(HugeNumber n)
    {
        return new HugeNumber(-n._sign, n._log);
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator+(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2)
    {
        if (n1._sign == 0)
        {
            return n2;
        }
        else if (n2._sign == 0)
        {
            return n1;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (n1._log > n2._log)
            {
                return new HugeNumber(n1._sign, n1._log + Math.Log10(1.0 + n1._sign * n2._sign * Math.Pow(10, n2._log - n1._log)));
            }
            else
            {
                return new HugeNumber(n2._sign, n2._log + Math.Log10(1.0 + n1._sign * n2._sign * Math.Pow(10, n1._log - n2._log)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static HugeNumber operator-(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2)
    {
        return n1 + -n2;
    }
    
    public double Log10()
    {
        if (_sign <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return _log;
    }
    
    public HugeNumber Pow(double exponent)
    {
        if (_sign < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return new HugeNumber(_sign, exponent * _log);
    }
    
    public HugeNumber Abs()
    {
        if (_sign >= 0)
            return this;
        return new HugeNumber(1, _log);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_sign == 0)
            return "0";
        else
            return string.Format("{0}{1}E{2:+0;-#}", _sign < 0 ? "-" : "", Math.Pow(10, _log - Math.Floor(_log)), Math.Floor(_log));
    }
    
    public bool Equals(HugeNumber n)
    {
        if (_sign == 0)
            return n._sign == 0;
        return _sign == n._sign && _log == n._log;
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is HugeNumber n)
            return Equals(n);
        return false;
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (_sign == 0)
            return 0;
        return _log.GetHashCode();
    }
    
    public int CompareTo(HugeNumber n)
    {
        if (_sign > n._sign)
            return 1;
        else if (_sign < n._sign)
            return -1;
        else if (_sign == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return _sign * _log.CompareTo(n._log);
    }
    
    public static bool operator<(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2) < 0;
    public static bool operator<=(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2) <= 0;
    public static bool operator>(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2) > 0;
    public static bool operator>=(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2) >= 0;
    public static bool operator==(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => n1.Equals(n2);
    public static bool operator!=(HugeNumber n1, HugeNumber n2) => !n1.Equals(n2);
}
```

Usage:

```
HugeNumber n = 10;
Console.WriteLine(n.Pow(10000)); // prints 1E+10000
```

Comment: `CompareTo(HugeNumber n) ... return _sign  * _log.CompareTo(n._log);` ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman right you are - thanks for spotting this error!